# Sidebar widget to show popular post not working?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

This is the code to display popular post on front end, however the problem is the data is not saving from the back end.  Like i want to show only 3 popular posts on front-end so i select the option 3 but its not saving. However when i pass the static value for `$popularpostcount` then this code works `echo $this->popularPosts($popularpostcount);` so i believe the problem is only saving the selected option.

I am new to plugin development so please let me know what mistake i am making while the development.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Popular Post Widget
Plugin URI: http://demo.test.com
Author: Swapnesh Kumar Sinha
Description: This is a plugin to show popular posts in sidebar as a widget.
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://swapneshsinha.wordpress.com
*/



class PopularPostWidget extends WP_Widget {

public function __construct() {
    //Widget actual processes
    $widget_options = array( 'Description' => 'Show Popular Posts' );
    parent::__construct( 'PopularPostWidget', 'Popular Post Widget', $widget_options); 
}

public function form( $instance ) {
    //outputs the options form on admin
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'popularpostcount' => '' ) );
$popularpostcount = $instance['popularpostcount'];  
echo $popularpostcount;
echo "Number of post to show "; 
echo "<select name='popularpostcount' id='popularpostcount'>";
    for( $i =1; $i<=5; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $i == $instance['popularpostcount'] )
        echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$i."</option>";
        else
        echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
    } 
echo "</select>";
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    //processes widget options to be saved
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['popularpostcount'] = $new_instance['popularpostcount'];
    return $instance;
}

public function widget( $args ,  $instance ) {
    //outputs the content of widget
    extract($args);
    $popularpostcount = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['popularpostcount']);
    echo  "<h2>Most Popular Posts</h2>";
    echo  "<ul>";
    echo $this->popularPosts($popularpostcount);
    echo  "</ul>";
}


public function popularPosts($num)
{
     global $wpdb;

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , $num");

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $id = $post->ID;
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $count = $post->comment_count;

        if ($count != 0) {
            $popular .= '<li>';
            $popular .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '" title="">' . $title.'</a> '." - ".$count;
            $popular .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $popular;
}


}

add_action( 'widgets_init' , create_function('', 'register_widget( "popularpostwidget" );' ) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line in **form** function:

```
echo "<select name='popularpostcount' id='popularpostcount'>";
```

with:

```
echo "<select name='".$this->get_field_name('popularpostcount')."' id='".$this->get_field_name('popularpostcount')."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: in addition to Kilan's answer, I would also recommend using the WordPress [**`selected()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) function:

```
echo "<select name='" . $this->get_field_name('popularpostcount') . "' id='popularpostcount'>";
    for( $i =1; $i<=5; $i++ )
    {
        echo "<option " . selected( $i == $instance['popularpostcount'] ) . " value='" . $i . "'>".$i."</option>";
    } 
echo "</select>";
```